# Responsive Web Design - Display None in Desktop

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to build a responsive web design and I have almost accomplished it.  The only issue is the navigation menu.  I created two versions of navigation menus - one for the desktop and the other for mobile.  I tried to do "display:none" in the desktop section of the CSS for the mobile version of the navigation, but if I do that, the menu won't be displayed at all in the mobile version.  What is the solution to solve this issue?  You can see the site here: http://rachelchaikof.com/testing/

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to achieve here. Of coarse if you set  "display:none", the menu won't be displayed. What else did you expect. You should instead change the css to get the desired display

Answer (score 2):

You want to add some CSS along the lines of this...

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
#mobile-nav {
display:none;
}
}
```

This will hide the mobile navigation menu if the screen size is less than 400px.
You might want to play around with the max width depending on what devices you are testing on.

Alternatively, you could use this PHP function to check if it is a mobile User Agent and then just wrap the mobile menu in a PHP if statement. 
http://erikastokes.com/php/how-to-test-if-a-browser-is-mobile.php

Answer (score 1):

If you write "display:none" outside of a media query, it would not show up. This is what I faced in one of my projects

I fixed it using something like:

```
        @media screen and (min-width:650px) { /*hide mobile menu for desktop*/
                .footer #exfootmenu{
                    display:none;
                }
            }       


        @media screen and (max-width:650px) {/*show mobile menu for mobile devices*/
                .footer #exfootmenu{
                    display:block;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, to get the effect you want, you would create a media query in your CSS Stylesheet for the mobile view and in that section, you would style the same `nav` elements from your desktop view in a different way.

I only viewed your site from my iPad this evening, so I didn't delve into your code.  Sorry if that was overly obvious.

Great content on the site!  I have a friend at uChicago who has done a ton of research on the social aspects of the implants cross-culture.  Amazing how little we hear of it in the US.

Comment: I apologize for confusion.  I want to hide #mobile-nav when people are viewing on the desktop computers.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not create a media query which has min-width:700px (or whatever you mobile breakpoint is) and within this media query you can display:none !important the #mobile-nav?

Answer (score 0):

Using the boiler plate (backwards compatibility) for html 5 and CSS with media queries, I have been able to get the display:none; to work in Moz. FireFox but unable to get it to work in Safari, Chrome and not going to even attempt it in IE!  You should be using media queries, responsive = mobile first.  Your mobile nav property should be set to display: block; or inline-block; then when you hit your screen snapping point set the property to display:none; this will work in firefox.  Any suggestion for the others... please do tell..